# Why do I get this error? Python (newb)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to programming. This is the assignment I got:

> Assignment Specifications
>
> For each of the following Richter scale measurements, your program
>   will perform the appropriate calculations and display the equivalent
>   amount of energy in joules and in tons of exploded TNT:
>
> ```
>  1.0
>
>  5.0
>
>  9.1 (Indonesia earthquake, 2004)
>
>  9.2 (Alaska earthquake, 1964)
>
>  9.5 (Chile earthquake, 1960; largest ever measured)
>
>  asdf (an invalid value)
> ```
>
> Your program will then:
>
>  prompt the user to enter a Richter scale measurement;
>
>  accept a floating point value representing that measurement (this
>   must be validated so that only valid numbers are entered);
>
>  perform the appropriate calculations;
>
>  display the equivalent amount of energy in joules and in tons of
>   exploded TNT for that userinputted value.
>
> Assignment Notes
>
> The Richter scale is a way to quantify the magnitude of an earthquake
>   using a base-10 logarithmic scale. The magnitude is defined as the
>   logarithm of the ratio of the amplitude of waves measured by a
>   seismograph to an arbitrarily small amplitude. An earthquake that
>   measures 5.0 on the Richter scale has a shaking amplitude 10 times
>   larger than one that measures 4.0, and corresponds to a 31.6 times
>   larger release of energy. The energy in joules released for a
>   particular Richter scale measurement is given by:
>
> Energy =10^(1.5*richter)+4.8
>
> where Energy is measured in joules and richter is the Richter scale
>   measurement (typically on a scale from 1-10 as a floating point
>   number). One ton of exploded TNT yields 4.184x109  joules. Thus, you
>   can relate the energy released in joules to tons of exploded TNT.

This is my code:

```
    run="yes"
    vr=1
    while run == "yes":

     while vr==1:
         RichterScale = (input("Please enter the value for the Richter magnitude:"))
         if RichterScale.isdigit():
              energy = 10**(1.5*RichterScale+4.8)
              print(("Energy released:"),energy,"Joules")
              vr=2
        else:
            vr=1

    run=input("Would you like to run this program again? yes/no: ")
print("Goodbye")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Please enter the value for the Richter magnitude:t
Please enter the value for the Richter magnitude:t
Please enter the value for the Richter magnitude:3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/python bridgin unit.py", line 8, in <module>
    energy = 10**(1.5*RichterScale+4.8)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Thanks

Comment: `RichterScale` is a string; what would you expect e.g. `1.5 * 'foo'` to be?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `foofc` ofcourse. Point is of course that `str.isdigit()` checks if the string consists of digits, but is not the same as `isinstance(RichterScale, int)`.

Comment: Also, note that `'9.1'.isdigit()` evaluates to `False`...

Answer (score 0):

You ask RichterScale if it is a digit and if it is, you proceed to treat it as if it is a number, when you haven't converted it yet. Try converting it to a float.

```
energy = 10**(1.5*(float(RichterScale))+4.8)
```